# How to filter a product by a datetime attribute in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, product, product-attribute, search, search-criteria

I am trying to filter products on a search by an attribute of type 'datetime'. The problem is it does not filter by it, so it shows all the results. I have tested other attributes and it works fine, any guesses on why? This is how my `SearchResults`object and product attribute look like:

[image]
[image]

```
    $filter1 = $this->filterBuilder
        ->setConditionType('eq')
        ->setField('some_attribute')
        ->setValue(self::SOME_VALUE)
        ->create()
    ;

    $now = new \DateTime();
    $filter2 = $this->filterBuilder
        ->setConditionType('gt')
        ->setField('departure_datetime')
        ->setValue('2018-01-15')
        ->create()
    ;

    $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
        ->addFilter($filter1)
        ->addFilter($filter2)
        ->create();

    $products = $this->productRepository->getList($searchCriteria);
```

Comment: Is it `departure_datetime` attribute? It's your custom attribute?

Comment: Yes it is a custom one. You can see its properties in the image above.

Comment: Can you post your code lines?

Comment: Sure which lines are you looking for?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh There I have posted my code